# Jquery was not found on this server

Tags: plugin-development, jquery

I have two pages, events.php from plugin1 index.php from plugin2. in events.php. I am including jquery for ajax loading

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a onclick="show_trend(<?php echo $event->output('#_EVENTID');?>)" >Trend</a>
```

This ajax load works fine. From this ajax call, I am calling a function and rendering a div in index.php. What I am doing is creating a highchart. For this I am including

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

in index.php function.

But I am not able to create charts beacuse jquery is not loading. In console, I am getting the following error

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
>
> **404.** That’s an error.
>
> The requested URL
>
> `/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js%20line%202%20%3E%20eval` was not found on this server.  That’s all we know.

Any suggestions?.

**Edit**

As suggested by  [TBI Infotech](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/52417/tbi-infotech)  i have done the following thing in my function

```
function em_bookings_events_table() {
........
.......
.......
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');


}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'em_bookings_events_table' );
```

but now jquery is not loading.

Comment: Why do you need to load the external jquery library from google? I don't think there is any compatibility issues for which you need to load older versions of jquery.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to include jquery  in your plugin is

```
/**
 * Proper way to enqueue scripts and styles
 */
function theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_name_scripts' );
```

Comment: can uplease expalin.  i have a function  like   function abc(){}  . inside this function i want to include jquery from cdn.. can u edit ur answer as per this?

Comment: The above answer also has the same thing it has a function theme_name_Script() in which jquery script have been called.

Comment: pls See my updated question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok the problem i found in your above code is you have not mentioned the path of your library

```
function em_bookings_events_table() {
........
.......
.......
wp_enqueue_script('name_of_script','place Path_of_your_jquery_file here');


}
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'em_bookings_events_table' );
```

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers, if you need to add/remove/modify anything in your original answer, do it in the form of an edit. :-)

Comment: Not necessary.. Using `wp_enqueue_script('jquery');` will load and enqueue the bundled jQuery from core. Here is the list of handles of the script already registered by core. http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#Default_Scripts_Included_and_Registered_by_WordPress

Comment: @Abhik then, can you tell me what is the issue

Comment: @NishamMahsin Your code looks just fine. May be you should remove any other codes adding jquery. Also, do a hard refresh on your browser.

Comment: @Abhik   i have some other html contents also there in function. is that any problem?